# MonoImage and Monoclass what's the difference?

Tags: mono

I noticed the ability in Mono to use either a MonoImage or a MonoClass. What's the difference? I finding it surprisingly hard to find a decent explanation on google.

Answer (score 1):

It's not like you can use them at will, as the question seems to imply.

As the name suggests, MonoImage represents a binary image (usually a file in the filesystem), what the ECMA specs call **module**. Say, both helloworld.exe and mscorlib.dll are represented in the embedding API as images.
Notice that an assembly (MonoAssembly) corresponds to one or more images and is a bit more high level.

MonoClass, on the other hand, represents a **class** (surprise!) as the ECMA specs intend them: a collection of fields, methods, properties, events etc with its own name and namespace, flags.